# Limit of sequence, sequence is formed by the root of an equation.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$f_n\colon[0, \infty) \to \Bbb R, \ f_n(x) \ = x^n-nx-1, \ \forall n \ge2$$
$$f_n(x)=0$$ Has one root, $$X_n \in (1, \infty)$$ Calculate $$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$$

$$f_n(X_n)= X_n^{n}-nX_n-1 = 0 \implies X_n = (nX_n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
$$1<X_n<n \implies 1<X_n<(1+n^2)^{\frac{1}{n}} \implies \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = 1  $$

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: It is ok$\phantom{}$

Comment: It looks good to me, +1.

Comment: Why is $\,X_n<n\,$ ? And how do you prove the existence $\,1<X_n\,$

Comment: because $X_n \in (1, \infty) \ \forall n \ge 2$ and $n \to \infty$

Comment: Yeah, well: I *knew* that, yet you still haven't answered the question: how do *you prove* both the existence of a root for each $\,n\ge 2\,$ and how do *you prove* there's one such root greater than 1? Other than that your work is fine (of course, it could be you don't *have* to prove anything...)

Comment: Well i proved it using one of the consequences of Rolle's theorem

Comment: But i know that one is right. Just i wasn't sure about this part.

Comment: In fsct, $1\leq x_n\leq 2$